# Counter Strike 1.6 openGL on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, games, opengl

So, after days of trial and error, head scratching and a few cases of beer I finally got CS 1.6 to run on my Ubuntu system. Albeit, in a window.

Here's the real kicker..it's rendering in SOFTWARE!!?? :(
Much sadness because it won't let me switch to openGL. When I do it spits out an error message saying ChoosePixelFormat failed.

I have my drivers (Asus Nvidia GTX 260) installed correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.